# How to implement splash screen image from a web service in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, web-services, xcode4.2, splash-screen

I am developing an iPhone application using restful web service.I want to implement splash screen through web service. Because I want to change that image dynamically. Is there any method for implementing this?

Comment: splash screen through web service? you want image to be fetched from web service?

Comment: what about use a generic image, (local image) to display while downloading the image from webserver. then change the generic image after download.

Comment: What do you mean by splash-screen? If you're talking about the actual launch image, it can't be changed. If you're talking about something that shows after your app is launched, just download the asset anytime and show it on the next launch.

Comment: Im little Confused... Is it possible or not.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Splash image is your [Default image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)
check the linked url for

> Providing Launch Images for Custom URL Schemes

But, this Default image, just shows for a little while, 2 seconds max,  so by the time you do the fetching of your image, the Default "splash" image is long gone,

also, you see this Default image when you have your app closed [not in background], so in order to see your Default image you will have to delete  your app from memory every time is closed...

Could you fetch the image and show it the next time the app is opened?

or you could show an image in a modal view? every time the app starts?

;)

Comment: I had the same idea in mind until I saw your reply! Great minds think alike! I'm pretty sure he is referring to a splash image with company logo or something similar. I'd also recommend using the fetched image in the next run of the app. Remember that your users will most typically want to use your app immediately, so there's no point in making them wait while you load an image that they probably couldn't care less about.

Comment: You *cannot* dynamically change the Default splash screen image baked into the application.  That would break code signing and cause your app to not be launch-able.

Comment: After first login am saved the splash screen image,then how can i  replace it with the default.png in my project bundle